# Is it safe to use types marked with the @Exported annotation introduced in Java 8?

Tags: java

Java 8 introduced the `@Exported` annotation and its documentation states the following:

> Indicates whether or not a JDK specific type or package is an exported part of the JDK suitable for use outside of the JDK implementation itself.

What is an *exported part of the JDK*? Should I use any types marked with such annotation? Is it considered safe?

For example, this annotation is present on the `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` class.

Comment: Uhm... It indicates wether or not a part of the JDK is exported? What's your actual question?

Comment: What part of your question is not answered by [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/jdk/Exported.html) which I found in 13 seconds?

Comment: Side-note, it'll be removed in JDK 9 http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nashorn-dev/2016-January/005804.html

Comment: @Tunaki That's an interesting side note. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: @EJP I've just rephrased my question. Actually, it wasn't clear enough (and just hope it's better now).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [its javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/jdk/Exported.html):

> Indicates whether or not a JDK specific type or package is an exported
>   part of the JDK suitable for use outside of the JDK implementation
>   itself. This annotation should only be applied to types and packages
>   outside of the Java SE namespaces of `java.*` and `javax.*` packages. For
>   example, certain portions of `com.sun.*` are official parts of the JDK
>   meant to be generally usable while other portions of `com.sun.*` are
>   not. This annotation type allows those portions to be easily and
>   programmatically distinguished.

So it's safe to use JDK-supplied classes annotated with that, but you should *not* be using that annotation in your own classes.